# Moving tab bar to bottom using React Native Elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, tabs

I'm making a mobile app with React Native and React Native Elements and cannot find a way to easily move my tab bar from top to the bottom of the screen.

Any tips? Or should I rather just use the Bottom Tabs Navigator from React Navigation?

Here is my current App.tsx that contains the Tabs:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Tab, TabView } from '@rneui/themed';
import Frontpage from './components/Frontpage';
import Calendar from './components/Calendar';
import Trainings from './components/Trainings';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <Tab
        value={index}
        onChange={(e) => setIndex(e)}
        indicatorStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
          height: 5,
        }}
        variant="default"
        containerStyle={{
          flex: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Item
          title="Home"
          titleStyle={{ fontSize: 16, color: "orange" }}
          buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#414141" }}
          icon={{ name: 'home', type: 'ionicon', color: 'orange' }}
        />
        <Tab.Item
          title="Calendar"
          titleStyle={{ fontSize: 16, color: "orange" }}
          buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#414141" }}
          icon={{ name: 'calendar', type: 'ionicon', color: 'orange' }}
        />
        <Tab.Item
          title="Trainings"
          titleStyle={{ fontSize: 16, color: "orange" }}
          buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#414141" }}
          icon={{ name: 'barbell-outline', type: 'ionicon', color: 'orange' }}
        />
      </Tab>

      <TabView value={index} onChange={setIndex} animationType="timing">
        <TabView.Item>
          <Frontpage />
        </TabView.Item>
        <TabView.Item>
          <Calendar />
        </TabView.Item>
        <TabView.Item>
          <Trainings />
        </TabView.Item>
      </TabView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with Bottom Tabs Navigator from React Navigation would be a much better idea.

You'd be getting

- proper navigation state management
- history
- deep linking
- tooling